# Android/Java java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am new at Android programming. I was trying to send a string from the left fragment to the right fragment through the main activity when Android threw me

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

For the left fragment, i wrote:

```
MyAdapter listAdapter=new MyAdapter(getData(),this.getActivity() );
        lv_list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lv_list); 
        lv_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                itemCallback.onItemSelected(parent, view, position);
            }
        });
```

for the main activity:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position) {
        MyAdapter listAdapter = (MyAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
        MainItem item = (MainItem) listAdapter.getItem(position);
        String title=item.getName();
        /*intent = new Intent(this, Fg_right.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);*/
        fg_right=new Fg_right();
        fg_right=Fg_right.newInstance(title);
        this.fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        this.fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fg_right, fg_right);
        this.fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        this.fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
```

for the right fragment:

```
public class Fg_right extends Fragment {  
     String title="";  
     TextView tv_right;
     public static Fg_right newInstance(String title){  
            Fg_right fg_right = new Fg_right();  
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putString("title", title);
            fg_right.setArguments(b);
            return fg_right;   
        }  
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fg_left, container, false);  
        Bundle arguments = this.getArguments();
        title=arguments.getString("title");
        this.tv_right = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_right);  
        tv_right.setText(title);
        return view;
    }
```

Thank you very much. All the suggestions would be appreciated.

I would also add the logcat output:

```js
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268): Process: com.example.projet3, PID: 1268
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projet3/com.example.projet3.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at com.example.projet3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  ... 10 more
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at com.example.projet3.Fg_right.onCreateView(Fg_right.java:28)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1045)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1147)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2116)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5328)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
10-11 14:24:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):  ... 20 more
```

Comment: What logcat says? Which line do you get NullPointerException?

Comment: You are inflating the layout `fg_left` for the Fg_right fragment class. Is that intentional? It's possible that you're setting tv_right's text property and tv_right is null.

Comment: I have put on the logcat

Comment: I have changed the layout fg_left to fg_right. but it didn't help.